# Hover text and show a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-tooltip

So basically I want some text to show a table when you hover your mouse over it, im using this basic jquery/CSS code:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script><script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="/resources/demos/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  });
  </script>
<style type="text/css">
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5em;
  }</style>
<p>
    <a href="#" title="I want the below table to be hovered here">Table</a> to be hovered</p>
```

And this is the HTML table that I would like to show when you hover over the text:

HTML:

```
<table border="4" bordercolor="black" cellpadding="15px" cellspacing="1" style="width: 800px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1>
                    <b style="list-style-type: disc; margin-left: 25px; margin-right:5px">This is my table</b></h1>
                <ul style="list-style-type: disc; margin-left: 40px; margin-right:5px">
                    <li>
                        <h1>
                            This is my first point</h1>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>
                            This is my second point</h1>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have obviously tried just replacing my "I want the below table to be hovered here" with my simple HTML table but its not working. So I somehow have to call the table, I could make the table a  but I cant call it properly anyhow..

Comment: You already seem to be using a tooltip plugin, why not put the table in the tooltip and instantiate the plugin on the element containing the text?

Comment: Why have you tagged with `themeroller` but not `jquery-ui`?   It's part of jquery-ui: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, my bad, im using a simple tooltip jquery ui, but im not following your suggestion though, in the tooltip as in the title=""?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy: 
in your Html : add an **element's Id** like that :

```
<a href="#" id="myHoverTitle" title="I want the below table to be hovered here">Table</a>
```

After, add **a second element's Id** for your table, and **hide him**(with: style : display:none) like that :

```
<table id="myContentHover" border="4" bordercolor="black" cellpadding="15px"
       cellspacing="1" style="width: 800px;display:none">
    <!-- Your table content -->
</table>
```

And, finally, use just the **Jquery toolTip**'s function for display your table, when your "myHoverTitle" html is on hover :

```
$(function() {
    $( '#myHoverTitle' ).tooltip({ content: $('#myContentHover').html() });
});
```

This Javascript create a "title" on your element "myHoverTitle" with the content of the element "myContentHover" ! You've the official JQueryUI tooltip documentation [here](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/).

Also, you can remove the title's attribute's content of the  element, it becomes useless:

```
<a href="#" id="myHoverTitle" title="I want the below table to be hovered here">Table</a>
```

To :

```
<a href="#" id="myHoverTitle" title="">Table</a>
```

Hope I help you.

Comment: One error of me : do not remove the title attribute, just remove the content of title attribute (i edit my post) and two error of you: 
When you create an id , you don't use a '#' character on your HTML! ;-)

it's not `id="#myHoverTitle"` but it's `id="myHoverTitle"

Comment: Replace also `<a href="#" id="myHoverTitle">Table</a>` by `<a href="#" id="myHoverTitle" title="">Table</a>` like my sample ;-)

Comment: Okay, it's strange, when I check on my localHost, that work with your code!! I just replace the `src="//code.[...]` by `src="http://code.[...]` on all <script> tags. But for me it's not the problem..

Answer (score 2):

Simple Explanation - wrap the table in a div and give it an id like 'hide_this_table' then you can

```
</script>

// start by hiding the div containing the table
$('#hide_this_table').hide();

// bind hover event
$('#some_text_id').hover(function() { // First function is a callback for the mouse over event
    $('#hide_this_table').show();
}, function() {                       // This second function is a callback for the mouse out event - you can remove it if you don't need it.
    $('#hide_this_table').hide();
});

</script>


<p id='some_text_id'>Show hidden table</p>

<div id="hide_this_table"> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>DOB</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Male</td>
            <td>1995</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

try it out...

Comment: let me update the above code to include a more somewhat simple approach. @honorem

Answer (score 1):

modify your js like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#demoTable").hide();
    $( "#demo" ).mouseover(function() {
        $("#demoTable").show();
    });
    $( "#demo" ).mouseout(function() {
        $("#demoTable").hide();
    });
});
```

and add a id to a tag and the table then wrap them in a div like this

```
<div>
    <p><a id="demo" href="#" title="I want the below table to be hovered here">Table</a> to be hovered</p>
    <table id="demoTable" border="4" bordercolor="black" cellpadding="15px" cellspacing="1" style="width: 800px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h1><b style="list-style-type: disc; margin-left: 25px; margin-right:5px">This is my table</b></h1>
                    <ul style="list-style-type: disc; margin-left: 40px; margin-right:5px">
                        <li>
                            <h1>This is my first point</h1>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h1>This is my second point</h1>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your js like this

```
$.widget("ui.tooltip", $.ui.tooltip, {
    options: {
        content: function () {
            return $(this).prop('title');
        }
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('.tblhover').attr('title', $('.tblcontent').remove().html())
    $(document).tooltip();
});
```

then add class into the (anchor tag and table tag) as per below HTML code

```
<a class="tblhover" href="#">Hover me</a>
<table class="tblcontent" border="4" bordercolor="black" cellpadding="15px" cellspacing="1">
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <h1><b style="list-style-type: disc; margin-left: 25px; margin-right:5px">This is my table</b></h1>
                 <ul style="list-style-type: disc; margin-left: 40px; margin-right:5px">
                     <li>
                         <h1>This is my first point</h1>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                         <h1>This is my second point</h1>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```